# Python - Safe Indexing with boolean

Tags: python, list, indexing, boolean, deap

I have some code which returns values from a list. I'm using strongly typed genetic programming (using the excellent DEAP module), but I realise that `1` & `0` is the same as `True` and `False`. This means where a function is expecting an integer, it might end up with a boolean function, which is causing be some issues.

For example:
`list = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`list[1]` returns `2`

`list[True]` also returns `2`

Is there a Pythonic way of preventing this?

Comment: What do you want returned for `data[True]` (By the way, don't name a variable `list`. Python took all the good names, so put `my` in front of your variables)?

Comment: Why would you use a boolean as a list index?

Comment: Or just check the type of the index variable using `isinstance(index, int)` and accordingly proceed.

Comment: You can add a condition to check the type of the index: `if type(index) is int:` or `if type(index) is bool:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own list that does not allow boolean indices:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, bool):
            raise TypeError('Index can only be an integer got a bool.')
        # in Python 3 use the shorter: super().__getitem__(item)
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(item)
```

Make an instance:

```
>>> L = MyList([1, 2, 3])
```

An integer works:

```
>>> L[1]
2
```

But `True` does not:

```
>>> L1[True]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-888-eab8e534ac87> in <module>()
----> 1 L1[True]

<ipython-input-876-2c7120e7790b> in __getitem__(self, item)
      2     def __getitem__(self, item):
      3         if isinstance(item, bool):
----> 4             raise TypeError('Index can only be an integer got a bool.')

TypeError: Index can only be an integer got a bool.
```

Override `__setitem__` accordingly to prevent setting values with booleans as indices.